# Json, Timer, Ajax, What is faster (for shared Chronometer)?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, json, client-side

I'm developing an application using ASP.Net.

For first the idea: "My WebApp needs an chronometerto be shared by users and all users will se the same value in cronometer. When a user clicks on a button, the cronometer needs to be restarted and all users will need to see that!"

All right, now I'd like to know what's the best choose to improve more performace an make sure  that all users will see the same value in chronometer?

Need I use JSon (with jquery in client side), Timer with UpdatePanel of Ajax Extensions, pure  Ajax (with JQuery) or any idea to suggested ? Any suggestion for how to shared a cronometer for all users in C# (put information in Cache or database) ?

Thanks all

Cheers

Comment: See this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803820/how-do-i-build-a-specialized-jquery-timer/7291411#7291411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for all users to see the same value in the chronometer. JQuery will be faster than an UpdatePanel (an UpdatePanel needs to post the whole page back to the server), but still some kind of polling to the server is needed. You could set the polling period to 1 second - in that case the difference in users' chronometers will be at the most 1 second. Even that value however is too low for a repeating Ajax request and could easily hog browser's resources.