# How to stop a Timer-X timer (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Timer-X](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TimerXAC)'s timerDelayCall function in order to have a repeating rotator on my page, which starts automatically as the page loads:

```
jQuery.timerDelayCall({
     interval: 2000,
     repeat: true,
     callback: function(timer) {
        ... (my rotator logic here)
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I'm trying to make a function that includes *stopping* that timer:

```
function signUp() {
    ... (timer stop code here)
}
```

The documentation stats that `timer.stop()` does that, but however I format it, I get errors about it not being declared.

I have tried every variation I can think of, such as:

```
timer.stop();

jQuery.timer.stop();

$(document).timer.stop();

jQuery.timerDelayCall({ callback: function(timer) { timer.stop() } });
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple - I come from a PHP background yet I'm new to javascript - but can't see what it is exactly. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803820/how-do-i-build-a-specialized-jquery-timer/7291411#7291411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the docs, it says that the `timerDelayCall` function will return the timer object.

```
var timer = jQuery.timerDelayCall({
     interval: 2000,
     repeat: true,
     callback: function(timer) {
        ... (my rotator logic here)
        }
    }
});

...

timer.stop();
```