# How to stop a jQuery rotate animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a audio multimedia player (turntable) based on jplayer plugin, and I'm using the rotate property on a div :

```
setInterval(    
    function () {
        $('#plateau').animate({
            rotate: '+=4deg'
        }, 0);
    },
    3);
```

Firstly, I would like to stop the rotation when a user clicks on another div.

Secondly, I would like to stop the rotation whith a maximum degree limitation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't worry about the 'bad English,' your question is clear and well written, and would be so even if you were a native English-speaker. I did, however, amend your question title to reflect the question *and* to remove the 'shouting.'

Comment: Use this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803820/how-do-i-build-a-specialized-jquery-timer/7291411#7291411

Answer (score 5):

well for one thing set setInterval equal to a var:

```
var timer = setInterval(...)
```

than you can stop it with:

```
clearInterval(timer)
```

and then to stop the animation do:

```
$('#plateau').stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the timeout a var!

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 0);
```

and when you need to stop it:

```
clearTimeout( timer );
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is returning a value. Store it, and then call `clearInterval` with this variable as a parameter

```
toto = setInterval(function(){…})
…
clearInterval(toto)
```

`clearInterval` will stop the regular execution of the function

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, I search a function who return the actual position in degree of the div, for can sync the movement of the arm with the actual playing position like on a real turntable player :

```
function rotation_bras(bras_rotation)
{
    /*var temps_actuel = $.jPlayer.convertTime(tt);*/ // Send the total time of the track
    // Begin position in degree 17deg
    // Maximum position in degree 40 deg
    // When a track is finish, the arm's turntable comeback at the initial position
    // The degree decalage should be depend to the total time of the track
    if(bras_rotation==true)
    {
        BrasTourne = setInterval(function(){$('#bras').animate({rotate: '+=0.1deg'}, 0);});
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(BrasTourne);
        $('#bras').stop();
    }
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: is this an answer? or a continuation of your own question?