# ASP.NET Timer Control's client side Tick event or jQuery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am looking for client-side Tick event of ASP.NET Timer control or jQuery equivalent timer plugin. Your suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803820/how-do-i-build-a-specialized-jquery-timer/7291411#7291411

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a temporary solution for this but I am not sure whether this is a good way or not. Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Thanks !

```
    function pageLoad(){
       var timer = $find('<%= Timer1.ClientID %>');                      
       timer._doPostback = function(){
         // Do something in client side before postback
         __doPostBack(this.get_uniqueID(),'');
       };
    }
```

Comment: It's surprising to me that there isn't a client-side event already for the Timer control, but alas there isn't, and this solution here does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [pluıgins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) with [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/). But i'm not sure with [Timer](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/) Control.

[Timer-X - Absolute Control](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TimerXAC)

[jCountdown Timer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCountdown)

[jQuery fjTimer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fjtimer)

Comment: You are welcome..If answer help you, please select an answer OR voted up.

Comment: +1 @Soner ... jCountdown is pretty interesting but I decided to go for ASP.NET Timer since I found a workaround without using any third-party plugins.